# Magento 2 - Get Shipping Code in Sales Order view in Admin

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shipping-methods, order-grid

I have a custom shipping module that passes some information into the Sales Order and the email.  The problem is that it shows the data even when the shipping method isn't used.  How can I get the shipping method so I can use it to only display the information if that shipping method is chosen?

This adds my data into the Sales Order in the Admin - view/adminhtml/templates/order/view

```
<?php
$formFields = $block->getOrderFormFields();
$shippingMethod = SOME CODE TO GET SHIPPING METHOD CODE;
?>
<?php if($shippingMethod == 'SHIPPING METHOD CODE'): ?>
    <section class="admin__page-section">
        <div class="admin__page-section-title">
            <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shipping Option') ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="admin__page-section-content">
            <div class="order-information">
                <div class="box">
                    <strong class="box-title"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Building Address') ?></span></strong>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($formFields->getCheckoutBuildingAddress()); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <strong class="box-title"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Floor Number') ?></span></strong>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($formFields->getCheckoutFloorNumber()); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box">
                    <strong class="box-title"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Room Number') ?></span></strong>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($formFields->getCheckoutRoomNumber()); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can I get the shipping code from the order so this only displays when the method is chosen?

UPDATE
I added a block class in Block/Order:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Order;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderItems extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get current order
     *
     * @return Order
     */

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getOrderItems()
    {
        $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

        return $order->getItems();

    }
}
```

And then tried this code in view/adminhtml/templates/order/view"

```
$order = $block->getOrderItems();
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
$code = $orderItems->getShippingMethod();

echo 'order' . $code;
```

Nothing happens.

UPDATE 9.16.2020
This works in my phtml file with the exception the Object Manager shouldn't be used this way and it doesn't get the current order ID when the page is displayed.

```
$orderId = 1;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);
  
// Fetch whole billing information
print_r($order->getBillingAddress()->getData());
   
// Fetch specific billing information
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getRegionId();
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getCountryId();
   
// Fetch whole shipping information
print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData());
   
// Fetch specific shipping information
echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getCity();
echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getRegionId();
echo $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
echo $order->getShippingMethod();
```

Thanks,
Stan

Comment: I have the solution here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322994/magento-2-using-object-manager Thanks,
Stan

Answer (score 0):

In admin side order object is there.

You need to add this line to call it.

```
$_order->getShippingMethod();
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks.  I tried 

`
$shipping = $_order->getShippingMethod();
echo 'shipping ' . $shipping;
`
And nothing shows.  I guess I am using it wrong.  What am I missing?

Comment: In your code $_order object is there?
Please get all details via object in $_order and then call it.

Comment: Via this code you can get order details.
$_order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $_order->getAllItems();

Comment: "In your code $_order object is there?" - Yes.  But  I guess that is where I get lost some.  "Please get all details via object in $_order and then call it." I am not sure what you mean.  Can you explain it some more please?

Comment: I tried this: $_order = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId); $orderItems = $_order->getAllItems();

echo 'order' . $_order;
print_r($_order);

And just got an "Undefined variable: _objectManager" when I tried to view the order in the admin.  I also tried using $_objectManager and got the same error.

Comment: I made an update above in my original answer - 9.16.2020

Answer (score 0):

You can get the shipping method by

```
$order->getShippingMethod();
```

or

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
```

Or May be you need to create new function in the block and send order object instead of order item object forEx:

```
  public function getOrder()
    {
        $order = $this->order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

        return $order;

    }
```

In HTML/view file, you will get shipping method using the below code.

```
$order->getShippingMethod();
```

I hope this will help you.

Please let me know if this will not work. If this will work then please accept this as ANSWER.
Thanks

Comment: Hi, I used the Block I have in my edit above (with your change for getOrder()) and tried the following in my phtml file:  echo $order->getShippingMethod;  and received the error: "Undefined variable: order" in my phtml file.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks, Stan

Comment: Please send me the code.

Comment: I sent an email and also made an update above in my original answer - 9.16.2020